# Allow sending folders over bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

When connecting to another machine over bluetooth, there is the option to "send files" in Settings>Bluetooth. The "file upload" dialog, then, does not allow sending a folder, only single files.

I have huge folders which I need to transfer to another notebook after a hd failure. It is impossible to have enough space to compress these folders in the small capacity SSD of my workplace computer, where the backup was saved. I'm detailing my situation to illustrate how crucial it is to be able to send folders, not only files, over bluetooth.

Any workaround for this?

Comment: As I said, it is not possible because there is not enough free space in the SSD.

Comment: According to https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-send-file.html, you CAN send more than one file. Use the CTRL button. If that doesn't work, then please file a bug report.

Comment: It does not work. If you select more than one file, and any one of them is a folder, then the "Select" button becomes iresponsive.

Comment: If you have any depth in a hierarchy folders inside folders, then it is clear that sending a folder is very different from sending a group of files. The directory structure is important. So I'm asking for a workaround.

Comment: I've managed to do it with scp (I was afraid the other system would not be discoverable in my local network). But bluetooth does not depend on an external network, so someone who needs to do directory transfers over bluetooth will be doomed while this is not supported.